# Can I undo updating Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I think updating Meteor might have broken my app. It was working, then I ran meteor update, and now it is not working. Can I do something like `meteor downgrade`?

Comment: paste your server allow/deny rules and I'll fix it for you.no need to downgrade

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Meteor 0.6.0 and above ships with a new distribution system. You can now pass the `--release` argument to any Meteor command and it will run against the requested release. For example, to bundle your app against Meteor 0.6.1, run: `meteor bundle --release 0.6.1`. Notably, this only works for post-0.6.0 releases.

If you want to pin your app to a specific release, run: `meteor update --release <release>`. This modifies the `.meteor/release` file in your app directory. Then simply run Meteor as usual. You'll still get notified when there's a new release available.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE**: As of Meteor 0.6.0, this functionality is available without using Meteorite. See [Avital's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15953863/1269037). (for versions > 0.6.0. To use functionality on versions less than 0.6.0 you can still use Meteorite:

If you want to control versions with your apps (so your existing app can still use an older version, or 0.57.1 (with the security bug fix) you can use meteorite: https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite

Install it via `npm install -g meteorite`

Its also helpful with loads of other packages from http://atmosphere.meteor.com.

To control the version of your app edit your smart.json to something with:

```
{
    "meteor": {
        "tag": "v0.5.7"
    }
}
```

Only the app you've already made will be affected & you can upgrade it when you're ready.

Comment: Thanks! That did it. Took me a minute to figure out that I needed to run the app with mrt instead of meteor haha.

Comment: This saved me!  Update broke my meteor.  Definitely use this if you need to revert to pre-0.6.0.  And be warned, updating could break your site without warning!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it is very hard. My best advice is to try and copy all the files from an app running the version you want, then paste your app's code in there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no meteor downgrade command from its CLI. The best and easy way if you have version control like GIT, just undo your recent changes by  `git stash save`, and run `meteor` again.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, I was able to effectively "downgrade" from a failed upgrade by editing the version number to a previous working release in the file:

C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local.meteor\meteor.bat

You need to change it to a version which has a corresponding folder in: .meteor\packages\meteor-tool